# Web browser account security

Tags: web-browser, browser-extensions

Please note that I've looked what similar questions have been addressed, but all I found was partial discussions.

My concerns is about web browser, password managers, cookies and sessions.

My goal is to make for someone impossible to log any of my websites while keeping things easy.

1. **Password Manager**
   The first thing to start is a password manager in order to have secure passwords and a master password to rule them all. It's a good thing. But not enough. The thing is, cookies are stored to keep users sign in.
2. **Session/Cookies manager**
   What I would like now is to be able to "log in" my browser as I would do in an OS. If someone access my browser he can use it, but not my account. If I enter a master password I'm suddenly connected to everything. This include password manager and not sharing cookies/not staying connected unless you proved your identity.

---

**What I tried:**
I tried LastPass 4.0 which looks cool. I made it logout when the browser I closed so that one could not log anywhere using my browser without the master key.

As I said the problem comes with cookies. Accounts like Google just keeps logging automatically, so it somehow bypass the password manager.

The perfect thing would be a LastPass that encrypts (or store elswhere) its cookies.

Anyone knows what could do it? Can't find extensions fitting my needs.

Thanks :)

Comment: It looks like that you can solve this with user accounts as OS level and that you aware of this but don't like to do it this way for unknown reason. Can you elaborate why you need this functionality in a browser plugin instead?

Comment: I'm partially using Windows. I don't trust session level security on windows because I never had issues breaking it. Last time was probably win7 but I found a quick step-by-step guide to remove a session password from a linux liveUSB. Not what I want for sure. My Linux are ok.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to handle your problem is to allow cookies only to stay during a session. Whenever you tear down your browser session, all cookies get purged.

Firefox at least has this feature built in, so you don't actually need any extension to do that for you. (Settings -> Privacy -> History -> drop down "with user specific settings" -> "accept cookies until" -> drop down "firefox is closed")

Given, this does not allow your cookies to be "unlocked" like passwords, but it removed the problem of being logged on.

Yet, such a plugin would be pretty neat. I can't believe there is none. If that is true: Go for it and make one - or a change request.